# How to import contacts from symbian mobile to android mobile?

Tags: contacts

I had Nokia 5610 ( S40 v5 ) mobile, and recently i got a new Android mobile ( HTC Desire S ). Now, when i put my sim card in my new phone i get all contacts which were saved in SIM memory, but there were lots of contacts in phone memory. I would like to import those also. How can i do that?

Comment: Is there any way to get the rest of your contacts onto the SIM card?

Answer (score 6):

You will need the [Nokia PC Suite](http://www.nokiausa.com/get-support-and-software/product-support/nokia-pc-suites/compatibility-and-download) tool but here is the easiest and fastest way.

1. Connect Nokia to PC using the PC-Suite
2. go to Contacts - press CTRL+A (select all)
3. go to Desktop/Subfolder - press CTRL+V (paste)
4. that will create a .vcf file for each contact
5. from a command prompt run the following command in the folderon your desktop where the files are saved:
   `copy *.vcf contacts.txt`
6. open http://google.com/contacts
7. choose "Import" link in google contacts.

Comment: Really good answer simple and efficient import

Comment: the `Nokia PC Suite` link is 404, does anyone know an alternative source?

Comment: i think i found a mirror here https://download.cnet.com/Nokia-PC-Suite/3000-10440_4-10598525.html

Answer (score 4):

If your old Symbian Phone have Bluetooth you can go to address book application, select all contacts and send them through Bluetooth to your new phone.

This will send a vcard file for each contact to your new phone and then you can import this data to your Android Phone.

I think the option to send a given contact via Bluetooth to another phone is:
Select the contact and the **Details > Options > Send business card**

Comment: This worked for me, and seems the simplest way, thanks.

Comment: Well, are you sure you won't have to send each contact separately?

Answer (score 0):

If you save a backup of your contacts onto your Symbian phone's SD card, it appears as an NBF file.  This is a zip file, which contains all your contacts in VCF format -- if you concatenate them all together, you can upload them to Google Contacts in one go.

For more details about how I discovered this, I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.aylett.co.uk/2011/01/03/migrating-contacts-from-s40-to-android/) at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Nokia PC suit to move all the contacts from the phone to the SIM card. This works in Samsung's Kies.